# How do I put a LiquidCrystal_I2C class in a Lcd class?

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to make my main code cleaner so I was thinking of making a Lcd class which I can use every time I need to print on lcd. So my main code every time I try to print text I need to call :

```
lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor(1,0);
lcd.print("Text 1st line");
lcd.setCursor(1,0);
lcd.print("Text 2nd line");
```

The problem is I need to create a class called Lcd which initialises the LCD display through LiquidCrystal_I2C.h and calls it's functions in order to print as I want.
Below I will post some code which is totally wrong but I guess it can give you the idea of what I am trying to do:

**LcdControl.hpp**

```
class LcdControl{
    public:
        LcdControl();
        void printOnLcd(int data,int column,int line);
        void printOnLcd(char data,int column,int line);
};
```

**LcdControl.cpp**

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "LcdControl.hpp"

LcdControl::LcdControl(){
    LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4);
    lcd.init();
    lcd.init();
    lcd.backlight();
}

void LcdControl::printOnLcd(int data,int column,int line){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(column,line);
    lcd.print(data);
}

void LcdControl::printOnLcd(char data,int column,int line){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(column,line);
    lcd.print(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use an inheritance model where the the base class is the original library LiquidCrystal_I2C and you simply create a new derived class, in this case LcdControl. In LcdControl, you simply pack in your additional methods. The only slight complexity is that you have to invoke the constructor of the base class LiquidCrystal_I2C when the constructor of the derived class LcdControl is called.

Here it is in a simulation:  https://wokwi.com/projects/349238619253244498

Code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

class LcdControl : public LiquidCrystal_I2C {
  public:

    LcdControl( uint8_t lcd_Addr, uint8_t lcd_cols, uint8_t lcd_rows) :
      // base class constructor
      LiquidCrystal_I2C ( lcd_Addr, lcd_cols, lcd_rows ) {
    }

  
    void printOnLcd(const char * data, int column, int line) {
      LcdControl::clear();
      LcdControl::setCursor(column, line);
      LcdControl::print(data);
    }

} ;

LcdControl lcd(0x27, 20, 4);



void setup() {

  Wire.begin() ;
  lcd.init() ;
  lcd.backlight();

  
  lcd.printOnLcd( "hello world2", 0 , 0 ) ;
  delay(1000) ;

  lcd.printOnLcd( "hello world3", 1 , 2 ) ;
  
}

void loop() {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Potentially, your `lcd` local of the constructor becomes member instead:

```cpp
class LcdControl{
    public:
        LcdControl();
    // ...
    private:
        LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd;
```

There it is accessible from all of your member functions and (without splitting hairs) exists for the lifetime of `LcdControl` variable. The way you have it currently the `lcd` instance is [local to](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/variable-scope-qualifiers/scope/) the constructor, so inaccessible elsewhere (e.g. inside `printOnLcd()`) and dies when the constructor returns.

The construction of the `lcd` member happens in the `LcdControl()` [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor):

```cpp
LcdControl::LcdControl()
    : lcd(0x27,20,4)
{
```

Newer standards of C++ allow some forms of initialization to be done where it's declared as member. I'm not going to recheck the standards now. But the above way should work regardless of which Arduino core and version you have.

The call to the lcd's `init()` may need to be done in an counterpart `init()`/`begin()` in your own class. When you do something that can fail in the constructor you have little opportunity to detect/handle this when done in the constructor on an embedded device like an Arduino where your class may be to make a global and where exceptions aren't supported; some Arduino's support exceptions and some don't. For an Arduino fallible part of initialization/contruction of often separated out so you can control how and where/when that failure happen, often in `setup()` and without reliance on exceptions.

There are a lot of ways to achieve something similar. The above seems closest to what you're attempting in the question. It may not necessarily make the most sense in your particular usage. You can want to have the class have a member pointer or member reference instead of a member instance, but you need to be more careful about their respective lifetimes. It is often a mistake to do initialization in inner layers of your code without providing the user of it any control. E.g. not allowing the user of your `LcdControl` class to initialize it's own `LiquidCrystal_I2C` instance and pass that in or to allow passing in the parameters for the `LcdControl` class to use.